# Authenticate a user in AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

Here is the sample code provided by AWS for authenticating a user

```
var authenticationData = {
    Username : 'username',
    Password : 'password',
};

var authenticationDetails = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);
var poolData = { UserPoolId : 'us-east-1_TcoKGbf7n',
    ClientId : '4pe2usejqcdmhi0a25jp4b5sh3'
};

var userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
var userData = {
    Username : 'username',
    Pool : userPool
};

var cognitoUser = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser(userData);
cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
    onSuccess: function (result) {
        var accessToken = result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();

        /* Use the idToken for Logins Map when Federating User Pools with identity pools or when passing through an Authorization Header to an API Gateway Authorizer*/
        var idToken = result.idToken.jwtToken;
    },

    onFailure: function(err) {
        alert(err);
    },

});
```

However, if I'm using AWS Lambda to handle the event, in this case, I can't retrieve the password from the event. What can I do to authenticate a user? Thank you : )

Comment: I think that code meant to be executed in front-end (browser)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a lambda to authenticate users. Cognito will take care of that. The code you have shared is for front end applications where it connects with the cognito service to authenticate user.

Comment: What if I want to add my own logic to authenticate users? Like retrieve and verify the password and assign my own token. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes it is. You can use the post sign in lambda trigger from cognito settings. This will trigger a lambda as soon as user attempts to sign in. It will also fetch the login details in event. I don't think you can give your own tokens though. For that you will have to look into custom authentication with cognito.

Comment: It seems like I can't access password directly from that event object. Inside userAttributes, it only contains 'sub', 'cognito:user_status', and 'email'.  And I think you might be right about the token, Cognito only allows me to customize the flow but not the implementation. I'm wondering that if I didn't even set up the resource server, what's that access token Cognito generated for?

Comment: Yes that would a security restriction which doesn't allow you to see password. But getting the password would be pointless anyway since you cannot extract password from cognito either so you would have nothing to compare it to. The access token is generated so that you can exchange it for temporary AWS credentials which would allow you access to AWS resources.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for your help! I am using Cognito just as a proxy server since my own auth server doesn't support OAuth2 and I only need something support OAuth2 so I can pass my access token from my auth server to Cognito. Then I  can integrate Cognito with my Alexa Skill to set up Account Linking. It seems like this is a dead end Since I can't even get the credential from Cognito and pass it to my auth server to get the token : (